# Given 3 points. What's the normal to the plane that contains these 3 points?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Given are these points $$v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2\\  3
> \end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 2\\  3\\  3 \end{pmatrix},
> v_3=\begin{pmatrix} 2\\  4\\  4 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Determine the normal to the plane which contains these 3 points.

My problem with this is I'm not sure what is really meant with "normal". Is it just the normal-vector or I will also need some parameter multiplied with the normal-vector?

So far I've done that but I'm not sure if that is all what is asked?

First calculate both direction vectors:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
3\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}-
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
4\\ 
4
\end{pmatrix}-
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now cross-product of these two vectors gives the normal vector:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

But now is this really an answer to the question? Or I need some parametric form of it? Please help :/

Comment: The normal is either the normal line to the plane or the normal vector. The normal line to the vector can be found easily by using another form of the [plane](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx). The normal line of the normal plane will be parallel to the original plane because of the double right angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The” normal to a plane typically really does refer to *any* vector that is normal to the plane. In other words, your suggested answer (or any non-zero scalar multiple of it) is perfectly fine.

*No* need to express the normal generally as $$k\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\quad(k\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}).$$